# Falha ao ler arquivo formatado via redirecionamento de entrada

Tags: c, arquivo

Estou tentando ler o seguinte arquivo via redirecionamento de entrada, porém o programa está entrando em loop infinito e com leituras totalmente erradas. Quando entro manualmente com os dados o programa executa conforme o esperado, parando quando pressiono `ctrl` + `d`.

Eis o arquivo:

```
728.78 Ferrari 05 1050 8
722.00 Williams 19 950 2
728.87 McLaren 14 750 9
722.32 Renault 27 930 14
698.92 RedBull 03 920 5
727.56 ToroRoso 26 1000 12
718.55 Haas 08 960 7
728.01 Mercedes 77 950 1
728.65 Ferrari 07 1050 3
722.11 Renault 30 930 10
728.50 Sauber 94 1000 11
728.39 Mercedes 44 950 6 
728.22 McLaren 02 750 13
722.76 Williams 18 950 4
700.01 RedBull 33 920 15
```

Eis o programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
    float weight;       // Peso do carro
    char  name[30];     // Nome do carro
    int number;         // Número do carro
    int power;          // Potência do carro
    int position;       // Posição do carro

} Car;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Car car;
    while (fscanf(stdin, "%f %s %d %d %d", &car.weight, car.name, &car.number, &car.power, &car.position) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%.2f %s %.2d %d %d\n", car.weight, car.name, car.number, car.power, car.position);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Seu código está perfeitamente funcional. Veja neste vídeo (https://asciinema.org/a/HBemldntsuM1haPmdjkTpexuY) que gravei do meu terminal Linux. Foi compilado com o GCC. O que pode estar acontecendo é que você fazendo algo errado ao redirecionar uma saída à entrada do programa. Ou seu compilador ou IDE podem ter algum bug. Passe mais informações, por favor - só não diga que é Dev-CPP!

Comment: Que estranho. Compilei com o gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: Eu diria que você está com outro problema. Como está fazendo o redirecionamento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema do seu código é que `fscanf()` [não é capaz de identificar caractere especial de final da linha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917550/difference-between-fgets-and-fscanf) `\n`, fazendo com que seu `while` não itere corretamente nas linhas da entrada.

Você pode ler linha a linha da sua entrada por meio da função `fgets()` e depois 'desmontar' cada uma dessas linhas usando a função `sscanf()`, veja só:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINHA_MAX_TAM   (100)

typedef struct
{
    float weight;       // Peso do carro
    char  name[30];     // Nome do carro
    int number;         // Número do carro
    int power;          // Potência do carro
    int position;       // Posição do carro

} Car;

int main(void)
{
    Car car;
    char linha[LINHA_MAX_TAM];

    while(fgets(linha, LINHA_MAX_TAM, stdin )) 
    {
        sscanf( linha, "%f %s %d %d %d", &car.weight, car.name, &car.number, &car.power, &car.position);
        printf("Peso: %.2f - Nome: %s - Numero: %.2d - Potencia: %d - Posicao: %d\n", car.weight, car.name, car.number, car.power, car.position);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Testando:

```
$ cat teste.txt | ./cars
Peso: 728.78 - Nome: Ferrari - Numero: 05 - Potencia: 1050 - Posicao: 8
Peso: 722.00 - Nome: Williams - Numero: 19 - Potencia: 950 - Posicao: 2
Peso: 728.87 - Nome: McLaren - Numero: 14 - Potencia: 750 - Posicao: 9
Peso: 722.32 - Nome: Renault - Numero: 27 - Potencia: 930 - Posicao: 14
Peso: 698.92 - Nome: RedBull - Numero: 03 - Potencia: 920 - Posicao: 5
Peso: 727.56 - Nome: ToroRoso - Numero: 26 - Potencia: 1000 - Posicao: 12
Peso: 718.55 - Nome: Haas - Numero: 08 - Potencia: 960 - Posicao: 7
Peso: 728.01 - Nome: Mercedes - Numero: 77 - Potencia: 950 - Posicao: 1
Peso: 728.65 - Nome: Ferrari - Numero: 07 - Potencia: 1050 - Posicao: 3
Peso: 722.11 - Nome: Renault - Numero: 30 - Potencia: 930 - Posicao: 10
Peso: 728.50 - Nome: Sauber - Numero: 94 - Potencia: 1000 - Posicao: 11
Peso: 728.39 - Nome: Mercedes - Numero: 44 - Potencia: 950 - Posicao: 6
Peso: 728.22 - Nome: McLaren - Numero: 02 - Potencia: 750 - Posicao: 13
Peso: 722.76 - Nome: Williams - Numero: 18 - Potencia: 950 - Posicao: 4
Peso: 700.01 - Nome: RedBull - Numero: 33 - Potencia: 920 - Posicao: 15
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/fWUwz6)

Comment: Tentei executar esse seu código mas a saída do primeiro carro está errada:
https://pastebin.com/Tncb8yBW

Comment: @MichaelPacheco Se não solucionou, não marque como resposta aceita não.

Comment: Somente o primeiro registro? O arquivo de entrada está em puro texto (ASCII) ? Esse comportamento pode estar ocorrendo por causa de uma coisa chamada [BOM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), presente em muitos arquivos UNICODE.

Comment: @MichaelPacheco: Veja o código funcioando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/fWUwz6)